# Unable to retrieve the records from oracle table by passing input as a value from XML payload

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am tring to pull the records from oracle table by passing value from XML in the where condition unfortnately
I am getting some rutime error like "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"  while executing the below query.

I tried different ways to execute the query but still, facing or getting the same error, so I would like to understnad thatwhat im missising in the query.

```
Table: Activity 
Table column is : act_xml(its clob object)

query :SELECT * from activity
where XMLExists('
declare default element namespace "urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3";
declare namespace ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2";
/Activity/Agent/Territory/ns2:SalesTeamId/ns2:ID[text()=$id]
'
passing act_xml, 10669 as "id"
);

payload:

<Activity
xmlns="urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3" RestrictionGroup="NONE"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="DiscussionActivityType" TransactionCode="I" CreatedOnDate="2019-11-21T16:04:29" UpdatedOnDate="2019-11-21T16:04:32" SourceCreatedByID="20303090" SourceCreatedByFirstName="Brandy" SourceCreatedByLastName="Nirider" SourceCreatedByRole="" SourceUpdatedByID="20303090" SourceUpdatedByFirstName="Brandy" SourceUpdatedByLastName="Nirider" SourceSystemCode="FSA" SystemOfRecordCode="FSA" RecordCompanyCode="AZN" SourceCountry="USA" SourceRegion="USA" SourceSystemGroup="VNA" SystemOfRecordGroup="VNA">
<ActivityId>
<ns2:ID
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2" SystemCode="VNA">a080P00001YZM7WQAX
</ns2:ID>
</ActivityId>
<Agent>
<EmployeeId>
<ns2:ID
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2" SystemCode="EMPLID">20303090
</ns2:ID>
</EmployeeId>
<Territory>
<ns2:TerritoryId
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">
<ns2:ID SystemCode="AZ">20070009</ns2:ID>
</ns2:TerritoryId>
<ns2:TerritoryCode
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">20070009
</ns2:TerritoryCode>
<ns2:Role
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">PSS
</ns2:Role>
<ns2:Description
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">Indianapolis C IN 2
</ns2:Description>
<ns2:SalesTeamId
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">
<ns2:ID SystemCode="AZ">10669</ns2:ID>
</ns2:SalesTeamId>
<ns2:SalesTeamCode
xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">D_ALPHA
</ns2:SalesTeamCode>
</Territory>
</Agent>
<Customer>
<AZCustomerMasterID SystemCode="AZ">58586509</AZCustomerMasterID>
<SourceCustomerID SystemCode="NAVVA">001U000000pMTySIAW</SourceCustomerID>
<CustomerType>HCP</CustomerType>
<CustomerActivityRole>participant</CustomerActivityRole>
</Customer>
<ReferenceContent>
<ReferenceName>Reported Adverse Reaction</ReferenceName>
<ReferenceType>action</ReferenceType>
<ReferenceId SystemCode="VNA">Reported Adverse Reaction</ReferenceId>
</ReferenceContent>
<StartDate>2019-11-21T16:03:00</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-11-21T16:03:00</EndDate>
<Topic>
<Name>BYDUREON BCISE</Name>
<Product>
<AZBrandId SystemCode="AZ">881574</AZBrandId>
<AZProductId SystemCode="AZ">881574</AZProductId>
<SourceProductId SystemCode=""/>
<ReferenceProductId SystemCode=""/>
<ProductName>BYDUREON BCISE</ProductName>
</Product>
</Topic>
<ActivityAction>discussion</ActivityAction>
<ActivityStatus>completed</ActivityStatus>
<ActivityInitiatedBy>AstraZeneca agent</ActivityInitiatedBy>
<ActivityOutcome>success with identified customer</ActivityOutcome>
<CommunicationMode>in person</CommunicationMode>
<LocationSetting>Selling</LocationSetting>
<SourceValues>
<Status>Submitted</Status>
<SubStatus>Completed</SubStatus>
<Applet>Actions</Applet>
<Activity>Detail Only</Activity>
<InteractionCategory>A_Selling (PSS)</InteractionCategory>
<Type>Selling</Type>
</SourceValues>
<Priority>2</Priority>
<DiscussionTool>N</DiscussionTool>
<ActivityTypeCheck>DiscussionActivityType</ActivityTypeCheck>
</Activity>
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate of your previous question then please [edit] your question to make it explicitly clear what the difference is between the two. If it is a duplicate then do not post the same question a second time just because you have not got an answer that you like; go back to your original question and edit it to improve it and clarify the problem and your expected output.

Comment: It is almost the same question but the query which shared by u is not working.

Comment: this is query:select
  act_xml
from
  activity
where
  XMLExists('declare default element namespace "urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3";
declare namespace ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2";
/Activity/Agent/Territory/ns2:SalesTeamId/ns2:ID[text()=10669]' passing act_xml);

Comment: If it is (almost) the same question and the answer is not working then go back to the previous question and clarify it so that you get the answer you want and make sure you have given a [MRE] including the details of the table structures, the sample data you are working with and what you expect the query to output.

Comment: I do and in the meanwhile can you help me to work with the above-mentioed query.